# Is it possible to have status compare against a different branch of forked repo?

Tags: github

A GitHub project has multiple branches, e.g. `master` & `develop`.
Changes are supposed to be done against `develop`.

After having forked the project and made some changes (based on `develop`) I pushed my changes to my fork as `feature/foobar`

The GitHub page of `feature/foobar` (in the forked repo) always shows the status against `project:master`.

Is this a setting I can change on my end? Comparing against `master` is mostly pointless since development is done against the `develop` branch.

Comment: Are you interested in the GitHub web page display, or the `git status` command output? (Pick one of the two, and delete the irrelevant tag.)

Comment: It's about the GitHub web page display.